# Visualising Real-Time Meteorological Observations in QGIS via JSON URL

Tags: json, gis, qgis, weather, real-time-data

The Australian Bureau of Meteorology provides live weather observations via a URL which displays JSON-formatted data (including temperature, wind speed, weather station coordinates etc.). I am aiming to bring this data into QGIS to show a real-time feed of weather observations which can then be joined to attributes created in the field. For example, when a feature is created, attributes such as temperature and wind speed can self populate on the basis of the closest weather station.

I don't have much experience bringing in JSON-formatted data into QGIS, especially via a URL to automatically update every 15 minutes.. so any help would be much appreciated!

The real-time weather data (for Hobart) is stored here: http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDT60801/IDT60801.94970.json

Which originates from this page: http://www.bom.gov.au/products/IDT60801/IDT60801.94970.shtml#other_formats

Coding is not my strong point so if anyone could guide me on how to tackle this problem that would be much appreciated!

-sharky

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Coding is not my strong point so I haven't yet figured out where to begin with this problem. I have encountered other people who are interested to know how to extract text from dynamic sources (such as JSON) for use in GIS so we would appreciate some guidance.